# Failed to connect to spark master:InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef; local class incompatible

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, serialversionuid

1. I Installed Spark on Linux machine. the version is spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.
2. and then I start the Spark using ./sbin/start-all.sh
3. I trid to run the examples JavaWordCount.java in Eclipse.
   but always failed. someone can helps me?
4. the version of Spark Master is:  Welcome to version 1.6.2, Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)
   the version of Spark on Eclipse side is:
   [image]

The exception is as follows:

```
16/07/25 12:01:20 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark:// hostname:7077...
16/07/25 12:01:20 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master hostname:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1223633663228316618, local class serialVersionUID = 18257903091306170
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
```

Comment: `local class incompatible:`: you are using two different versions of Spark at each end. Use the same version. This is really a Spark bug but using a consistent version will fix it.

Comment: @EJP  can you give me more details information? which version should I use?  on the Spark machine:  ./spark-shell , I can see the following information Welcome to version 1.6.2, Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)

Comment: You should use the latest version you can get your hands on.

Comment: I downloaded all the latest version for both end, but still not work

Comment: Then you didn't deploy it correctly.

Comment: Instead of using ./sbin/start-all.sh use ./sbin/start-master.sh Your linux should run as master. Your eclipse should connect to master as slave. Please refer [link1](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/23976/vonnect-hdp-24-spark-remotely-failed.html),[link2](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by version not matched.
I tried to install hadoop and use spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar, it works fine now.