# Connecting to a remote Spark master - Java / Scala

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I created a 3 node (1 master, 2 workers) `Apache Spark` cluster in AWS. I'm able to submit jobs to the cluster from the master, however I cannot get it work remotely.

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "/usr/local/spark/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://ec2-54-245-111-320.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

I can see from the master:

```
Spark Master at spark://ip-171-13-22-125.ec2.internal:7077
URL: spark://ip-171-13-22-125.ec2.internal:7077
REST URL: spark://ip-171-13-22-125.ec2.internal:6066 (cluster mode)
```

so when I execute `SimpleApp.scala` from my local machine, it fails to connect to the the `Spark Master`:

```
2017-02-04 19:59:44,074 INFO  [appclient-register-master-threadpool-0] client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint (Logging.scala:54)  [] - Connecting to master spark://ec2-54-245-111-320.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077...
2017-02-04 19:59:44,166 WARN  [appclient-register-master-threadpool-0] client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint (Logging.scala:87)  [] - Failed to connect to spark://ec2-54-245-111-320.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77) ~[spark-core_2.10-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75) ~[spark-core_2.10-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) ~[scala-library-2.10.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59) ~[spark-core_2.10-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
```

However, I know it would have worked if I had set the master to `local`, because then it would run locally. However, I want to have my client connecting to this remote master. How can I accomplish that? The Apache configuration looks file. I can even telnet to that public DNS and port, I also configured `/etc/hosts` with the public DNS and hostname for each of the `EC2` instances.
I want to be able to submit jobs to this remote master, what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For binding master host-name/IP go to your spark installation conf directory (spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/conf) and create spark-env.sh file using below command.

```
cp spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh
```

Open spark-env.sh file in vi editor and add below line with host-name/IP of your master.

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=ec2-54-245-111-320.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Stop and start Spark using stop-all.sh and start-all.sh. Now you can use it to connect remote master using

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("SparkSample")
  .master("spark://ec2-54-245-111-320.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077")
  .getOrCreate()
```

For more information on setting environment variables please check http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts

Comment: Abaghel, I could create a single instance in AWS and just edit the spark-env?

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace? Are you using same version of spark for connecting? Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559597/failed-to-connect-to-spark-masterinvalidclassexception-org-apache-spark-rpc-rp

Comment: yes, I will post. I'm using the same version: spark 2.0.2. I will create a spark instance (a single node) which I could share in this question.

Comment: @perrohunter just follow the steps mentioned in this solution.

Comment: Would anybody please explain why this answer is supposed to work and on which machine I am to cast those spells? This is like mega not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem regrading launching local code on remote cluster:
The job is getting submitted, and resources are allocated properly, but the driver process on my local machine claims that cluster doesn't accepted

> WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources;
>   check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have
>   sufficient resources

On the remote machine's logs i noticed, that it is accepting the job with driver-url from my local network

> ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command:
>   "/opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java" "-cp"
>   "/opt/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*"
>   "-Xmx16384M" "-Dspark.driver.port=59399"
>   "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend"
>   "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.88.227:59399"
>   "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "172.31.50.134" "--cores" "4"
>   "--app-id" "app-20190318121936-0000" "--worker-url"
>   "spark://Worker@172.31.50.134:45999"

So mine issues was with the wrong hostname resolving for driver process

Comment: @nEO sorry, it was almost year ago, i don't remember how i fixed this